# Get information from newly arrived mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I am developing a VBA program that will be triggered for newly arrived email in Outlook. (Criteria is set at Outlook's "Rules and Alerts".)

The emails are expected to have:-

"subject" field consists of: "WO_name/Task_name"

First line of "Body" consists of : "operation"

"String_1", "String_2", "String_3" and the sender's email address are to be fed into a batch file (4 arguments in total)

This is my code:

```vb
Sub ChangeSubjectThenSend(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

WO = readCommand(Item.Subject, 1)
Task = readCommand(Item.Subject, 2)

Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim sText As String
For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body
Next olItem

Shell ("C:\warehouse\WO\checkInOutTask\taskOperations.bat " & WO & " " & Task & " " & Item.SenderEmailAddress & " " & sText), vbNormalFocus

End Sub

Public Function readCommand(str As String, position As Integer) As String
Dim Tempstr() As String
If position >= 1 Then
Tempstr = Split(str, "/")
readCommand = Tempstr(position - 1)
End If

End Function
```

It feeds the contents of the email entry currently selected in Outlook rather than the newly arrived email.

How do I make the script run against the newly arrived email instead?

Comment: You want your code to run everytime a new mail arrivess? Then you should consider using `ThisOutlookSession` event. You'll see there the `Inbox Add Item` event.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the Outlook Visual Basic Editor, the minimum Project Explorer you will see is something like:

[image: Minimum Project Explorer]

If you clck the plus against "Project1 (VbaProject.OTM)", it will expand to:

[image: First level folders]

It is probable that your initial view will be this with Forms (if any) and Modules already expanded.  But "Microsoft Office Outlook Objects" will probably not be expanded.  Click the plus against it to get:

[image: Expanded Microsoft Office Outlook Objects]

Click "ThisOutlookSession" to select it and you will get:

[image: ThisOutlookSession]

"ThisOutlookSession" is like a module but it has extra privileges.  In particular you can specify event routines here.  Yours will be empty but here you can see the code I have created for you.

`Private Sub Application_MAPILogonComplete()` is called when the logon process is complete.  I have included code to initialise `Public WithEvents MyNewItems As Outlook.Items`.  Because of this initialisation, `Private Sub myNewItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)` is called every time a new item is added to Inbox.  My code simply displays the new item's subject in the immediate window but, if you replace my code with yours, you should be able to get the effect you seek.

Add the code below to your "ThisOutlookSession" then exit and re-enter Outlook.  You may get enough new emails anyway but, if not, send yourself some emails.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents MyNewItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_MAPILogonComplete()

  Dim NS As NameSpace

  Set NS = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

  With NS
    Set MyNewItems = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  End With

End Sub
Private Sub myNewItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

  With Item
    Debug.Print "Item added to Inbox with Subject: " & .Subject
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply code to the newly arrived mail, do not select anything.

Instead use `Item` passed in `(Item As MailItem)`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeSubjectThenSend(Item As MailItem)

WO = readCommand(Item.subject, 1)
Task = readCommand(Item.subject, 2)

Dim sText As String
sText = Item.body

Shell ("C:\warehouse\WO\checkInOutTask\taskOperations.bat " & WO & " " & Task & " " & Item.SenderEmailAddress & " " & sText), vbNormalFocus

End Sub


Public Function readCommand(str As String, position As Long) As String

Dim Tempstr() As String

If position >= 1 Then
    Tempstr = Split(str, "/")
    readCommand = Tempstr(position - 1)
End If

End Function
```